# r check and replace stuck data

Tags: r

There are two sensors. The collected data should be changing with time. How can identify the data stuck and replace it with another sensor?

```
a<- c(1:24)
b<- seq(0.1,2.4,0.1)
c<- c(0.05,0.2,0.3,rep(0.4,18),2.2,2.3,2.4)
d<- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

so the data has

```
d
a   b    c
1 0.1 0.05
2 0.2 0.20
3 0.3 0.30
4 0.4 0.40
5 0.5 0.40
6 0.6 0.40
7 0.7 0.40
8 0.8 0.40
9 0.9 0.40
10 1.0 0.40
11 1.1 0.40
12 1.2 0.40
13 1.3 0.40
14 1.4 0.40
15 1.5 0.40
16 1.6 0.40
17 1.7 0.40
18 1.8 0.40
19 1.9 0.40
20 2.0 0.40
21 2.1 0.40
22 2.2 2.20
23 2.3 2.30
24 2.4 2.40
```

Sensor c stuck at 0.4 from time a4 to a20, is there a quick way to identify it and replace the stuck part using data from sensor b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new column `c_updated` is what you want. I've created some helpful columns (`c_previous` and `c_is_stuck`) which you can remove if you want.

```
library(dplyr)

a<- c(1:24)
b<- seq(0.1,2.4,0.1)
c<- c(0.05,0.2,0.3,rep(0.4,18),2.2,2.3,2.4)
d<- data.frame(a,b,c)

d %>%
  mutate(c_previous = lag(c, default = 0),            # get previous measurement for sensor c
         c_is_stuck = ifelse(c == c_previous, 1 ,0),  # flag stuck for sensor c when current measurement is same as previous one
         c_updated = ifelse(c_is_stuck == 1, b, c))   # if sensor c is stuck use measurement from sensor b


#     a   b    c c_previous c_is_stuck c_updated
# 1   1 0.1 0.05       0.00          0      0.05
# 2   2 0.2 0.20       0.05          0      0.20
# 3   3 0.3 0.30       0.20          0      0.30
# 4   4 0.4 0.40       0.30          0      0.40
# 5   5 0.5 0.40       0.40          1      0.50
# 6   6 0.6 0.40       0.40          1      0.60
# 7   7 0.7 0.40       0.40          1      0.70
# 8   8 0.8 0.40       0.40          1      0.80
# 9   9 0.9 0.40       0.40          1      0.90
# 10 10 1.0 0.40       0.40          1      1.00
# 11 11 1.1 0.40       0.40          1      1.10
# 12 12 1.2 0.40       0.40          1      1.20
# 13 13 1.3 0.40       0.40          1      1.30
# 14 14 1.4 0.40       0.40          1      1.40
# 15 15 1.5 0.40       0.40          1      1.50
# 16 16 1.6 0.40       0.40          1      1.60
# 17 17 1.7 0.40       0.40          1      1.70
# 18 18 1.8 0.40       0.40          1      1.80
# 19 19 1.9 0.40       0.40          1      1.90
# 20 20 2.0 0.40       0.40          1      2.00
# 21 21 2.1 0.40       0.40          1      2.10
# 22 22 2.2 2.20       0.40          0      2.20
# 23 23 2.3 2.30       2.20          0      2.30
# 24 24 2.4 2.40       2.30          0      2.40
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple way. Duplicate the `c` column with an offset of 1 and check if the two values are identical. If so, take the value from `b`.

```
a<- c(1:24)
b<- seq(0.1,2.4,0.1)
c<- c(0.05,0.2,0.3,rep(0.4,18),2.2,2.3,2.4)
d<- data.frame(a,b,c)

d$d <- c(NA, d$c[1:23])

d$replaced <- ifelse(d$c == d$d, d$b, d$c)

    a   b    c    d replaced
1   1 0.1 0.05   NA       NA
2   2 0.2 0.20 0.05      0.2
3   3 0.3 0.30 0.20      0.3
4   4 0.4 0.40 0.30      0.4
5   5 0.5 0.40 0.40      0.5
6   6 0.6 0.40 0.40      0.6
7   7 0.7 0.40 0.40      0.7
8   8 0.8 0.40 0.40      0.8
9   9 0.9 0.40 0.40      0.9
10 10 1.0 0.40 0.40      1.0
11 11 1.1 0.40 0.40      1.1
12 12 1.2 0.40 0.40      1.2
13 13 1.3 0.40 0.40      1.3
14 14 1.4 0.40 0.40      1.4
15 15 1.5 0.40 0.40      1.5
16 16 1.6 0.40 0.40      1.6
17 17 1.7 0.40 0.40      1.7
18 18 1.8 0.40 0.40      1.8
19 19 1.9 0.40 0.40      1.9
20 20 2.0 0.40 0.40      2.0
21 21 2.1 0.40 0.40      2.1
22 22 2.2 2.20 0.40      2.2
23 23 2.3 2.30 2.20      2.3
24 24 2.4 2.40 2.30      2.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The bellow solution is as basic as it gets I think. No additional packages required. Cheers!

```
a<- c(1:24)
b<- seq(0.1,2.4,0.1)
c<- c(0.05,0.2,0.3,rep(0.4,18),2.2,2.3,2.4)
d<- data.frame(a,b,c)

d$diff.b <- c(NA, diff(d$b))
d$diff.c <- c(NA, diff(d$c))

stuck.index <- which(d$diff.c==0)

d[stuck.index, "c"] <- d[stuck.index, "b"]  

# changing to original data frame format

d$diff.b <- NULL
d$diff.c <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If it helped maybe you could give it a thumbs up? :)